# How create Jenkins Build Pipeline depends on test result?

Tags: jenkins, testng, pipeline

I have 3 Jenkins jobs. Smoke tests, critical path test (part 1), critical path test (part 2).
Now it starts one by one. I need create build PipeLine depends on test result. I need to take into account the results of a single test (@Test annotation in TestNG), ignoring the overall result of test suite.

I want to get the configuration like this:

Smoke tests -> If specified test passed then run critical path test Part 1 and Part 2 on different nodes

So, please tell me how depends in Jenkins only on one tests result (not all suite)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that task by using 2 Jenkins extensions:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin

1. Create properties file from test. File contains property, that indicate result of test step status
2. With EnvInject Plugin add new step into Jenkins Job (step must be after test run) and inject parameter value (from file created at first step)
3. Create build flow with Build Flow Plugin
4. Write groovy script:

   ```
   smokeTest = build( "Run_Smoke_Test" )
   def isTestStepSuccessful = smokeTest.environment.get( "TestStepSuccessful" )
   if (isTestStepSuccessful != "false") {
       parallel (
           { 
             build("Run_Critical_Path_Part_1_Test")
             build("Run_Critical_Path_Part_3_Test") 
           },
           {
             build("Run_Critical_Path_Part_2_Test") 
           }
       )
   }
   build( "Run_Critical_Path_Final_Test" )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some of build log analysis plugins:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task
Scan build output, and downgrade build result to failure on specific text. 
Next in downstream item check option "Build after other projects are built" in build triggers section.  Set proper upstream item name and set proper trigger result.